# Angular use left right arrow key to move between table cells

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, arrow-keys

hope i can get some ideas here
I have a material table with a row of input fields
[image]

i would like to use left and right arrow key to move between cells instead of `tab`
at the moment i am able to use `keyup.arrowleft` and `right` in console to trigger event and move to the index next to it but i do not know how it can be done to move focus from one cell to the one next to it.

Any help would be appreciate thank you so much and below is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g8qhrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.key" *ngFor="let col of columnsSchema">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    {{ col?.label }}
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-form-field (keyup.arrowright)="moveRight(col.key)" (keyup.arrowleft)="moveLeft(col.key)">
      <input [type]="col?.type" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[col.key]" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

TS file

```
export interface SpecimenType {
  Test1: string;
  Test2: string;
  Test3: string;
  Test4: string;
  
}
const COLUMNS_SCHEMA = [
  {
    key: 'Test1',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Test1'
  },
  {
    key: 'Test2',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Test2'
  },
  {
    key: 'Test3',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Test3'
  },
  {
    key: 'Test4',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Test4'
  },
  
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor() {}

  columnsSchema: any = COLUMNS_SCHEMA;

  selectedSpecimanType!: SpecimenType;

  
  displayedColumns: string[] = COLUMNS_SCHEMA.map(col => col.key);
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = [{ Test1: 0, Test2: 0, Test3: 0, Test4: 0}];
  }

  moveRight(event: any) {
    console.log('moveright', event);
    const position = this.displayedColumns.findIndex(result => event === result);
    console.log(this.displayedColumns[position + 1]);
  }
  moveLeft(event: any) {
    console.log('moveleft', event);
    const position = this.displayedColumns.findIndex(result => event === result);
    console.log(this.displayedColumns[position - 1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you only have to move within a row? What happen when it reach the last column in the row? Should it go the first column in the same row OR first column in the next row below it?

Comment: Hi, yes only need to move within a row, when it reach the last column in the row it can just stop there or back to the first column in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to first add [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#:%7E:text=Template%20variables%20help%20you%20use%20data%20from%20one%20part%20of%20a%20template%20in%20another%20part%20of%20the%20template.%20Use%20template%20variables%20to%20perform%20tasks%20such%20as%20respond%20to%20user%20input%20or%20finely%20tune%20your%20application%27s%20forms.) to the input in the html. In this case, I use `#myInput`. Then replaced `moveRight(col.key)` with `moveRight($event)`. I will leave it to you to do the same for the `moveLeft`.

#### app.component.html

```html
...
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <mat-form-field 
    (keyup.arrowright)="moveRight($event)"
    (keyup.arrowleft)="moveLeft(col.key)">

      <input [type]="col?.type" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[col.key]"  #myInput/>

  </mat-form-field>
</td>
...
```

In the TS file, you will need to use `@ViewChildren` to query all the template variable we tagged in the html.

#### app.component.ts

```js
//... import stuff here

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChildren('myInput', {read: ELementRef})
  private _inputList!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ...

  public moveRight(event: any) {

    // get the currentIndex
    const currentIndex = this.inputList
      .reduce((matchedIndex, input, index) => {
        if(input.nativeElement === event.srcElement) {
          matchedIndex = index;
        }

        return matchedIndex;
      }, -1);

    if(currentIndex === this.inputList.length -1) {
      // move back to the first input or do nothing.
      return;
    }
    
    // Focus the next right sibling input.
    this.inputList.get(currentIndex + 1).nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

I noticed that there is an error related to `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your stackBlitz. I need to add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to import in `app.module.ts`.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports [
    ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ....
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```